# Use guard statement to see there is error

Tags: swift

We use `guard` to make sure some useful data exist before we progress deeper, can we use `guard` to check for error existence and exit early? or just standard `if` statement.

```
endpoint?.getArray() { data, error in
    guard error == nil else {
      print(error!)
      return 
    }

    guard let data = data else {
      print("no data")
      return 
    }

     print(data[0])
}
```

**EDIT**

If using `if` statement, does it read better?

```
endpoint?.getArray() { data, error in
    if error != nil {
      print(error!)
      return 
    }

    guard let data = data else {
      print("no data")
      return 
    }

     print(data[0])
}
```

Comment: Just use an IF.  That's now how guard works.  Guard is an optional binder just like `if let`

Comment: You actually do. Put the `return` statements after `print`. @TheValyreanGroup `guard` can also be used for boolean expressions.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: can we use `guard` to check there is an error and exit the scope

Comment: Your code seems to be doing that. What's the problem?

Comment: @vadian What's the point? `IF` will do the same exact thing and make more sense.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup `guard` is not exclusively an optional binder and to **exit** scopes `guard` makes perfect sense.

Comment: @vadian ...especially when `data` returns `nil` when there is an error as many of Apple's APIs do. Then you can just write `guard let data = data else { /* error handling */ return }`

Comment: @jjatie Yes! See now that makes sense.  Using a guard to check conditionally to `nil` just doesn't make much sense as `guard` is used for other things 99% of the time.  And an IF can do if just fine.

Comment: @KentLiau I prefer the second, but change your first statement back to an `if error == nil` that makes the most sense.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup I don't get it, `if error == nil`, do you mean `!=`

Comment: Yes, sorry.  `if error != nil`

Answer (score 2):

- Basically `guard` is almost indispensable if you want to use the bound unwrapped value later in code.
- If you need the unwrapped value right before the exit when the condition evaluates to `true` use `if let`.
- For everything else it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score -1):

guard requires a "return", which this is what you want. Using 'if' could be a problem if you "forgot" the return...